# Continuously monitor files opened/accessed by a process

Tags: linux, display, process, lsof

`lsof -p 12345`  will list all the files opened by process whose pid is 12345 but only for a particular instant of time.

How can we continuously monitor a process from the start to end(until process is terminated) to list/show every single file accessed by the process during its whole lifetime?

Comment: [How do I monitor opened files of a process in realtime?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58887/44425)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try with `strace -p 12345`; it should do what you are trying to achieve.

The output can be filtered to only display opened files ([Dan D.'s comment](https://superuser.com/questions/348738/continuously-monitor-files-opened-accessed-by-a-process#comment452144_348751)):

```
strace -e open -p 12345
```

*Note:* you can also trace quickly running processes with `strace -e open <command>`.

Comment: output is not friendly and too much extra things.

Comment: You can fix that by piping - `strace -p {pid} | grep -i "Open" | tee files_opened.log`. The key is `grep`, which lets you filter the output for the system call you want (e.g. `open()`).

Comment: @Ninefingers Actually `strace` can do that better than `grep` with the `-e` option: `strace -e open`

Comment: When I kill the strace command, it also kills the thing it is tracing. Why is this happening (cygwin)?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Be aware that the cygwin-`strace` is probably not the Linux-`strace`, as `strace` is a Linux-specific tool. Cygwin builds a Unix-compatiblity layer, and does not try to be Linux. With cygwin, you're probably better off using the original Windows tools.

Answer (score 8):

The new utility **fatrace** will do this: https://launchpad.net/fatrace/

```
sudo fatrace | grep '(6514)'
```

Don't use the -p option, it means the opposite of what it means in lsof or other utilities.

Answer (score 3):

This will loop re-running your command and clearing the screen each time:

```
watch "lsof -p 12345"
```

WARNING: this will miss quick file accesses and is only suitable to see long standing files

Comment: This is somewhat clumsy compared to the other answer using `strace`.

Comment: That's inaccurate solution - a process may use files in between executions of `lsof`

Comment: @Dor you can set the timing of lsof to sub 1 second and increase it's precision.  While it's clumsy compared to others, you are wrong in that it's an inaccurate solution.

Comment: If your looking at a long file operation (like a database backup) this may a good simple alternative.